# Activating fingerprint login on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 16ALC7

Tags: lenovo, laptop

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I'm trying to figure out how to enable fingerprint login on my laptop.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci`, `lsusb` and `sudo lshw` with an edit to improve the quality of your question.